# Which regex to use?

Tags: java, regex

i have expressions like :

```
-3-5
or -3--5
or 3-5
 or  3-+5
or -3-+5
```

I need to extact the numbers , splitting on the "-" sign between them i.e in the above cases i would need, 
-3 and 5, -3 and -5 , 3 and 5, 3 and +5 , -3 and +5.
I have tried using this:

```
String s[] = str.split("[+-]?\\d+\\-[+-]?\\d+");
    int len = s.length;
       for(int i=0;i<len;i++)System.out.println(s[i]);
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to split with this regular expression:

```
str.split("\\b-")
```

The word boundary `\b` should only match before or after a digit so that in combination with `-` only the following `-` as the range indicator is matched:

```
-3-5, -3--5 , 3-5,3-+5,-3-+5
  ^     ^      ^   ^     ^
```

Comment: Really good! I would have ditched split and ended up with some long regex matcher. Yours is much better.

Comment: could someone please explain what was wrong with the regex i had tried?

Comment: @pranay - your regex was fine, but splinting is wrong in that case. You may have wanted to `match`, and add capturing groups for both numbers.

Comment: @Kobi: could you give an example please

Comment: @pranay - Well, not in Java at the moment, but this should make it clearer: http://regexr.com?2rso3 . Note that your regex is correct, I just added groups so I can capture the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Crossposted to forums.sun.com.

This is not a job for REs by themselves. You need a scanner to return operators and numbers, and an expression parser. Consider -3-------5.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is pretty ok. Split is  not the choice though since you are trying to match the expression to your string - not split the string using it:

Here is some code that can make use of your expression to obtain what you want:

```
String a = "-90--80";
Pattern x = Pattern.compile("([+-]?\\d+)\\-([+-]?\\d+)");
Matcher m = x.matcher(a);
if(m.find()){
 System.out.println(m.group(1));
 System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```